# Question from Cartan-Eilenberg, Chapter 6, exercise 5

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

The exercise problem is this; consider a unital ring $A$. For each right $A$-module $M$ and left ideal $I$ of $A$, TFAE.

(a) For each relation $\:\sum _{i} a_iu_i=0 \:(a_i\in M, u_i\in I)$ there exists elements $\:b_j\in M, \lambda_{ij} \in A$, finite in number, such that $\:a_i = \sum_{j} b_j\lambda_{ij}, \: \sum_{i} \lambda_{ij}u_i=0$.

(b) The map $M\otimes_A I \rightarrow M\otimes_A A\:$ is a monomorphism.

(c) Tor$^{A}_{1} (M, A/I) = 0$.

(d) For each exact sequence $\:0\rightarrow N\rightarrow P\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0\:$ with $P$ a projective $A$-module, we have $N\cap (PI)=NI$.

(e) There exists an exact sequence  $\:0\rightarrow N\rightarrow P\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0\:$ with a projective $A$-module $P$ such that $N\cap (PI)=NI$.

I know that the first three statements are equivalent to flatness of $M$, but I don't know why they are equivalent to (d) and (e). I tried to prove that (c) implies (d), using the basic property of Tor functor and the fact that $N/IN$ is isomorphic to $N \otimes_A (A/I)\:$ for each $A$-module $N$, but I don't see where the projectiveness of $P$ comes in. I'm utterly clueless, so I need a little hint (or the proof, which is even better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need $P$ projective for the implications (c) => (d) => (e), only for the implication (e) => (c).  Projectivity gives you an exact sequence $0 \to {\rm Tor}_1(M,A/I) \to N/IN \to P/IP$ (without projectivity you don't have the 0), and so this shows ${\rm Tor}_1$ is isomorphic to the kernel.  The implication (e) => (c) follows by identifying the kernel of the map $N/IN \to P/IP$ with $(N \cap IP)/IN$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have only one thing to confirm; we need projectivity of P because projective modules are flat, and Tor$\_{1}(P, A/I)=0$, right?

Comment: @ashlessashtray Correct.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad to help.